# Java how do I create a large number (1million) without printing E (i want actual)

Tags: java

I want to call:

```
RandomNumber.nextInt(328) * 1000000
```

and I want a number like **145,543,120** without getting 1.4E8

**I need this number outputted to a file as actual**

Comment: convert it to a string!!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Do you want to display the number to the user? Are you looking at it during debugging?

Comment: Wait, that's an integer, integers are never displayed in exponential notation. You're not telling us something.

Comment: @trutheality the only other thing I left out was its within a stringBuffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the commas, here's the formatter:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int value = rand.nextInt(328) * 100000;
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
System.out.println(format.format(value));
```